# Class query not detecting the corresponding instances in Protégé OWL

Tags: owl, protege

I have MultiPetsOwner class in my ontology, and with the current set up I expect 2 Instances to be detected for it (Harry and Alex).

But when I run the DL Query "hasPet min 2 Animal" for it, there are no corresponding instances.

At the same time, the DL Query "hasPet some Animal" seems to work - it gives me the PetOwner class instances I expected.

What am I doing wrong? If the "hasPet min 2 Animal" query is incorrect, what should I use instead to get all the MultiPetsOwner*s*?

The contents of my .owl file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/5xcriLRE

Comment: It's great you've shared your data, but can you please also share your query? Or do you mean, you run the reasoner?

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov My query is "hasPet min 2 Animal" - I'm trying to get the instances of MultiPetsOwner

Comment: That's not a valid SPARQL query.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov The question is about DL Query, not SPARQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWL is working in Open World Assumption. In your case, that means than it is not assumed the individuals are different. You have to assert it explicitly. In Protégé, this is done when all individuals are selected, in your case all animals, and then Edit -> "Make all individuals different".

If you run the `hasPet min 2 Animal` it will give you the expected results, but you can see them already after running the reasoner in the inferred instances of the class `MultiPetsOwner`.

Answer (score 3):

In OWL there is no Unique Names Assumption (UNA), which means two individuals with a different URI are not necessarily different from each other. This means, a standard OWL reasoner, which is what's used for DL queries can't answer your query without having the information in your ontology that e.g. two animals `a` and `b` are not the same individuals (via owl:differentFrom):

Your ontology:

```
hasPet(x, a), Animal(a)
hasPet(x, b), Animal(b)

-> Q: hasPet min 2 Animal? 
-> A: NO RESULT
```

With the additional OWL axiom

```
hasPet(x, a), Animal(a)
hasPet(x, b), Animal(b)
a ≠ b

-> Q: hasPet min 2 Animal? 
-> A: x
```

Alternative way: Use SPARQL as query language

```sql
SELECT ?x WHERE {
  ?x :hasPet ?pet .
  ?pet a :Animal
} GROUP BY ?x 
  HAVING(COUNT(?pet) >= 2)
```

Note, this query might probably not take needed inferences into account.